# how to print return function in Python

Tags: python, scipy

It is very strange in Python that, I need specify the return vector and print them out. My original code is:

```
import scipy.cluster.vq as spk
result = spk.kmeans2(dataset, 5)
print result.label
```

or like this:

```
import scipy.cluster.vq as spk
print spk.kmeans2(dataset, 5).label
```

I got an error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'label'`

However, when I change the code to:

```
import scipy.cluster.vq as spk
code, label = spk.kmeans2(dataset, 5)
print label
```

The code works fine. So what is the problem?

Comment: umm... because it returns a tuple?

Comment: It is not weird, you are just unpacking the returned value. Also keep in mind that a function in Python can return multiple things which are actually wrapped up with a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a tuple. A tuple can be accessed with index. So the right way to access the data will be

```
import scipy.cluster.vq as spa
print spk.kmeans2(dataset, 5)[0]  # for code
print spk.kmeans2(dataset, 5)[1]  # for label
```

That should work. Do read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html for more info

Comment: That's not the right way. You processed the data twice! Tuple unpacking is a better option.

Comment: Thats right... Just an example to explain the concept of the positions of the data.